# Calculating Fraunhofer diffraction patterns

Tags: optics, diffraction

How does one calculate the Fraunhofer diffraction pattern for the following arrangement of slits:

|...|...........|...|

..a.....3a......a

(Four slits arranged linearly, spaced a distance a, 3a and a apart.)

The width of the single slits can be neglected, so that the transmission function can be expressed as sum of delta-functions.

Comment: I'm adding the homework tag because this is a classic homework question. If it's not, please add more detail and remove the tag.

Comment: Yes, fair enough.  I think I have figured out the solution.

$$ U(\theta) = 2 \left( cos(5\pi \frac{\sin\theta}{\lambda}) + cos(3\pi \frac{\sin\theta}{\lambda}) \right) $$

If anyone violently disagrees with that, I'd be very happy to know about it!;-)

Comment: @SimonS Sir how you arrived at that result , was it same as the method given in the answer ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Fraunhofer diffraction pattern is simply the (square absolute value of) the Fourier transform of the transmission function. If you put your first line at $x=0$ then the transmission function is
$$f(x)=\delta(x)+\delta(x-a)+\delta(x-4a)+\delta(x-5a)$$
and its Fourier transform is 
$$1 + e^{iak}+e^{4ika}+e^{5ika}$$
Which can be simplified to 
$$\left(\cos\left[\frac{3 a k}{2}\right]+\cos\left[\frac{5 a k}{2}\right]\right) \left(\cos\left[\frac{5 a k}{2}\right]+i \sin\left[\frac{5 a k}{2}\right]\right)$$
Taking the square of the absolute value, you get 
$$\left(\cos\left[\frac{3 a k}{2}\right]+\cos\left[\frac{5 a k}{2}\right]\right)^2$$
(I omitted all along multiplicative factors)

Comment: Right.  I centered my slit/transmission function in the middle of the diagram, but yes, I should have squared the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: The squaring is optional really. It gives you the intensity you would measure, but the complex valued field is meaningful on its own as well, just not as an observable.

Comment: yohBS, I'm not sure if the homework tag was on the problem when you posted this, but just in case, I wanted to make sure you're aware of our [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) that we shouldn't be posting complete answers to homework questions. Any time that happens the answer may be temporarily deleted.

Comment: The homework tag was not there, if I recall correctly, but even if it was, I was not aware of this policy. I will abide in the future...

Comment: For the record, this was not a homework problem for me and I did not put that tag there.  I simply wanted to understand it for myself.  My days of undergrad physics are well and truly over.